# Should users with Multiple downvote on their question without comment be allowed to consult with the Meta Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion

Some question are getting multiple downvote without comment. Would it be better if we could provide a channel for these victims, such that they could consult with seniors on Meta Stackoverflow about why their question being downvoted?

Perhaps by limiting only those who receive more than 2 downvote without comment could start consulting.

One possible benefit of doing so, are they will learn how they should be asking the question? Rather than giving them no clue of what's going on and repeat the mistake again.

Comment: I have a feeling I'm going to be the victim soon in here. :D

Comment: This already exists.  Users can already post on meta if they want feedback on a particular contribution.

Comment: If you know that the question is a low quality question that isn't going to be well received then *why did you ask it*?  Why didn't you take the time to improve on it such that you felt it wouldn't be poorly received before asking it?

Comment: If you're new to the site it's not exactly obvious @Servy; I'd be a lot more worried about those who are genuinely trying to improve being downvoted here and others just assuming that it's a get out of jail card without really understanding what's happening.

Comment: Some users have even posted outlines of questions here on meta asking whether it's on-topic, and how to improve things _before_ posting the actual question.

Comment: Related: [I've just been down voted! How should I react?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121350)

Comment: @Servy *New* users cannot do so, and they may not know it exists. I'm not saying we need to change anything, but its worth noting that we could improve/change the functionality.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET We have First Posts that's specifically designed to cover that case.  Anyone who can't post on meta will have their posts entered into that queue where users can give them more detailed feedback on what problems they may have with their post.

Comment: Don't worry about down votes on Meta, @Yeo, they don't count against your SO reputation.

Comment: @Servy what about Second Posts (and subsequent), where OP still doesn't have sufficient rep to come here?

Comment: @BillWoodger First Posts is a slight misnomer; all users' posts where the user has less than 10 rep go into First Posts.  So if they haven't gotten a single upvote on any previous posts, they'll still be reviewed.

Comment: @Servy Thanks. Didn't know that :-) Means a whole lot of stuff goes through there. I don't usually see much, though.

Comment: @Servy 2500-ish First Posts today. I did a highly scientific count on one page of current questions and 10 out of 50 were <= 10 rep. Not sure that's adding up.

Comment: @BillWoodger First Posts pushes pretty hard to get people to upvote the posts there, which results in those users no longer having less than 10 rep.

Comment: @Servy OK, but I'm not saying there are not enough visible low-rep users (which that could explain) but how that fits with 2500 First Posts reported reviewed. If there are more than I saw as "started off low" in that list of questions, it seems to make 2500 reviews even less likely to cover the total. Perhaps I'll have a longer think.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Servy stated in [the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295409/should-users-with-multiple-downvote-on-their-question-without-comment-be-allowed#comment199021_295409), users can already ask questions here on meta.SO about how to improve their question.

Also, lots of times when a question has multiple downvotes, the question will also end up being closed. Once the question is closed it will show information to why the question was closed. So the user can learn about what they did that was not up to the standards of the site question asking policies.